# How to pass a parameter to class constraint

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In there a generic constructor with parameter constraint in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852837/in-there-a-generic-constructor-with-parameter-constraint-in-c-sharp)

I have this code that passes the object type dynamically:

```
public static void Retion<T>() where T : DataContext, new()
{
    using (T entitiesContext = new T())
    {...}
```

My problem is that I need a constructor with parameters, like this:

```
   public static void Retion<T>(String conn) where T : DataContext, new()
    {
        using (T entitiesContext = new T(conn))
        {...}
```

When I try this I get an error: Error 137 'T': cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the actual type of T have a constructor with this signature, even if the Datacontext have it. That's why the constraints cannot be used when using parameters.

Comment: @SteveB for that matter, there is no guarantee the actual type would have an empty constructor as well, but its enforced by constraints. I dont see a difference. This feature (what OP is asking) will be really handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
using (T entitiesContext = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new[]{conn}))
```