# How to implement a GenericDbContext in GenericRepository?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have more DbContext's. I want to use just one GenericRepository.
I try to create a GenericDbContextFactory. But how can I create TContext? What do I have to do, so the context is not null?

```
public class GenericRepository<TTable, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TTable, TContext>
    where TTable : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    private TContext _context { get; set; } = default!;
    private IGenericDbContextFactory _contextFactory;
    private DbSet<TTable> _table { get; set; } = default!;
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public GenericRepository(IGenericDbContextFactory contextFactory, string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
        _context = GetNew();
    }

    public virtual void Reset()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = GetNew();
    }

    public TContext GetNew()
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.Create(_connectionString) as TContext;
        _table = context.Set<TTable>();

        return context;
    }

    public async Task Save()
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Reset();
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

        _context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
    }


public class GenericDbContextFactory : IGenericDbContextFactory
{
    public DbContext Create(string connectionString)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            var context = new DbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
            return context;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("ConnectionId");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class `GenericDbContext`?

Comment: That's depends on DbContext. I shall add it.

Comment: It's Entity Framework Core? If yes, what version?

Comment: Yes EF & Dependency Injection

Comment: What version? EF Core or EF 6? Can you add the corresponding tags?

Comment: <PackageReference Include="EntityFramework" Version="6.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.9">

Comment: You have mixed reference to the old alias `Entity Framework 6` and the new alias `Entity Framework Core`. See [Compare EF Core & EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/)

Comment: You need uninstall the package `EntityFramework`.

Comment: And than it will work?

Comment: Maybe... The `DbContext` class can be from the package `EntityFramework` or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. But it's a welcome cleaning.

Comment: DbContext is already generic. It's a multi-entity Repository and Unit-of-Work. All entities are defines as single-entity DbSet repositories. There's no need for a `GenericRepository` like this, it actually *breaks* the Unit-of-Work pattern

Comment: The reason this code breaks UoW is because DbContext already detects changes to *all* the entities it tracks. These are only persisted when `SaveChanges` is called, thus providing UoW semantics. Until that moment, DbContext doesn't even keep a connection to the database. `SaveChanges` persists all changes in a single internal database transaction. If you want to "rollback" just dispose the DbContext

Comment: The question's code on the other hand can't roll back anything. It does leak DbContext instances and their tracked objects though, because `GenericRepository` doesn't implement IDisposable and therefore doesn't dispose the DbContext it wraps

Comment: With a single defined DbContext, the code works fine. But then I have to create for all DbContext objects a  new GenericRepository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetNew` return null (throw `NullReferenceException`instead?) because :

```cs
public TContext GetNew()
{
    // GenericDbContextFactory.Create return GenericDbContext
    GenericDbContext genericDbContext = _contextFactory.Create(_connectionString);
    // GenericDbContext isn't TContext, then as operator return null
    // context is set with null
    var context = genericDbContext as TContext;
    // throw NullReference Exception
    _table = context.Set<TTable>();
    return context;
}
```

To resolve this, you need `GenericDbContextFactory.Create` return `TContext` instance. But it isn't possible to have generic constrain with constructor parameters. One solution :

```cs
public class GenericRepository<TTable, TContext> : IGenericRepository<TTable, TContext>
    where TTable : class
    where TContext : GenericDbContext, new()
{
    public TContext GetNew()
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.Create<TContext>(_connectionString);
        _table = context.Set<TTable>();
        return context;
    }

    ...
}

public class GenericDbContextFactory : IGenericDbContextFactory
{
    public TContext Create<TContext>(string connectionString) where TContext : GenericDbContext, new()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
        {
            var context = new TContext();
            context.Initialize(connectionString);
            return context;
        }
        ...
    }
}

public abstract class GenericDbContext : DbContext
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public GenericDbContext()
    { }

    public abstract void Initialize(string connectionString)
        => _connectionString = connectionString;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```

You can found other possibilities in this other question :

[Is there a generic constructor with parameter constraint in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852837/is-there-a-generic-constructor-with-parameter-constraint-in-c)

---

But please read carefully the remark of @PanagiotisKanavos. It's a really bad implementation of the repository pattern, because EF Core isn't hidden.

To use `GenericRepository`, it need to specify the real DbContext type and DbSet is raw exposed. With a good repository, you only manipulate the repository, without know what is under the hood.

In the majority of cases, EF Core can be use directly like a repository.

Comment: I don't how to specify the real DbContext. That's what I'm searching the whole day.

Comment: The context shows all DbSets. I implement your code in my Repository.

Comment: You want determine TContext from TTable without specify the need to specify TContext?

Comment: When I am debugging and I hit in GetNew() the "_table = context.DbSet..." I get the error message: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions<TContext> object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

Comment: I use AddDbContext (in program.cs)  as well OnConfiguring.

Comment: It's like it don't call `GenericDbContext.OnConfiguring`. In the real DbContext class, is this method overloaded? If yes, you need the first ligne to be `base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);`