# Using generics in functions that create objects

Tags: c#, generics

I have a custom class called `CustomList`, which works the same as an array but allows for adding elements and dynamically increases in size as necessary.

I have the function `MergeSort` that I want to work with `CustomList` and standard arrays.

I've tried the following:

```
    public class Sorter<T> where T : IEnsemble<T>
    {
        public static IEnsemble<T> MergeSort(IEnsemble<T> array)
        {
            IEnsemble<T> res;
            if (array.Length > 1)
            {
                IEnsemble<T> left = MergeSort(array[0..(array.Length / 2)]);
                IEnsemble<T> right = MergeSort(array[(array.Length / 2)..]);
                res = MergeSort(left, right);
                return res;
            }
            else { return array; }

        }

        public static IEnsemble<T> MergeSort(IEnsemble<T> left, IEnsemble<T> right)
        {
            int leftPointer = 0;
            int rightPointer = 0;
            IEnsemble<T> res = new IEnsemble<T>(left.Length + right.Length);
            while (leftPointer < left.Length || rightPointer < right.Length)
            {
                if (rightPointer == right.Length || (leftPointer < left.Length && left[leftPointer].CompareTo(right[rightPointer]) < 0))
                {
                    res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = left[leftPointer];
                    leftPointer++;
                }
                else
                {
                    res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = right[rightPointer];
                    rightPointer++;
                }
            }
            return res;
        }
```

with the interface being as such:

```
    public interface IEnsemble<T>
    {
        T this[int i] { get; set; }
        IEnsemble<T> this[Range range] { get; }
        int Length { get; }
    }
```

There are two problems that I can find that I don't know how to fix.

1. I can't get the range operation to return the base class, and so I have to return the interface. I don't know if this is an issue since I can't get it to run due to:
2. `IEnsemble<T> res = new IEnsemble<T>(left.Length + right.Length);` won't work since `IEnsemble` is an interface.

In summary: I want to create a generic function for merge sorting on a custom collection class that has indexing and range, that also works with standard arrays. Is this possible, and if so how do I do it?

Comment: What version of C# are you using?  [C# 11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11), [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-80) or something even older?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problems depends on the C# version you are using:

1. Your first problem can be resolved by extending `IEnsemble` with some derived interface that specifies the type returned by `this[Range range]` to be the ensemble type itself.
2. In C# 11/.NET 7 your second problem can be solved by using a [static virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/static-virtual-interface-members) creation method in your `IEnsemble` interface.

   Prior to C# 11 there is no language support for static virtual methods, or for [parameterized constructor constraints on generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1852837), so you will need to modify your design, e.g. by passing a `Func<int, TEnsemble> creator` delegate into your `MergeSort()` methods.

Thus **in C# 11** your `IEnsemble` could be defined as follows:

```
public interface IEnsemble<TItem>
{
    TItem this[int i] { get; set; }
    IEnsemble<TItem> this[Range range] { get; }
    int Length { get; }
}

public interface IEnsemble<TItem, out TEnsemble> : IEnsemble<TItem> where TEnsemble : IEnsemble<TItem, TEnsemble>
{
    static abstract TEnsemble Create(int length); // Abstract static creation method
    new TEnsemble this[Range range] { get; }
}

public class Sorter<TItem, TEnsemble> 
    where TEnsemble : IEnsemble<TItem, TEnsemble>, new()
    where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{
    public static TEnsemble MergeSort(TEnsemble array)
    {
        if (array.Length > 1)
        {
            var left = MergeSort(array[0..(array.Length / 2)]);
            var right = MergeSort(array[(array.Length / 2)..]);
            return MergeSort(left, right);
        }
        else { return array; }
    }

    public static TEnsemble MergeSort(TEnsemble left, TEnsemble right)
    {
        (int leftPointer, int rightPointer) = (0, 0);
        var res = TEnsemble.Create(left.Length + right.Length); // Invoke the static creation method
        while (leftPointer < left.Length || rightPointer < right.Length)
        {
            if (rightPointer == right.Length || (leftPointer < left.Length && left[leftPointer].CompareTo(right[rightPointer]) < 0))
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = left[leftPointer];
                leftPointer++;
            }
            else
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = right[rightPointer];
                rightPointer++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

And implemented e.g. as follows:

```
public static partial class EnsembleExtensions
{
    public static Ensemble<TItem> OrderByMergeSort<TItem>(this Ensemble<TItem> ensemble) where TItem : IComparable<TItem> 
        => Sorter<TItem, Ensemble<TItem>>.MergeSort(ensemble);
}

public class Ensemble<TItem> : IEnsemble<TItem, Ensemble<TItem>>
{
    readonly TItem [] array;
    public Ensemble(int length) => this.array = new TItem[length];
    public Ensemble() : this(0) {}
    public Ensemble(TItem [] array) => this.array = array ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
    public static Ensemble<TItem> Create(int length) => new Ensemble<TItem>(length); // Imlementation of the static method
    
    public int Length => array.Length;
    public TItem this[int i] { get => array[i]; set => array[i] = value; }
    public Ensemble<TItem> this[Range range] => new Ensemble<TItem>(array[range]);
    IEnsemble<TItem> IEnsemble<TItem>.this[Range range] => this[range];
}
```

Notes:

- I extended `IEnsemble<TItem>` rather than simply adding `out TEnsemble` to it because there may be situations in your code  where you are simply accessing individual items of an ensemble and do not care about the concrete type returned for a range, e.g.

  ```
  public static partial class EnsembleExtensions
  {
      public static IEnumerable<TItem> AsEnumerable<TItem>(this IEnsemble<TItem> ensemble) => 
          Enumerable.Range(0, ensemble.Length).Select(i => ensemble[i]);
  }
  ```

  In such cases passing in an `IEnsemble<TItem>` will be sufficient (and may work more easily with type inferencing).
- In `Sorter<TItem, TEnsemble>` you need to constrain `TItem` to implement `IComparable<TItem>` to call `CompareTo()`.
- You may want to make `IEnsemble<TItem>` implement `IEnumerable<TItem>`.

.NET 7 demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwtr84).

**Before C# 11** there is nothing resembling an abstract static interface method that can be overridden, or a parameterized constructor constraint, so you will need to modify your design somehow.  One option would be simply to pass a creator delegate into your merge sort method:

```
public interface IEnsemble<TItem>
{
    TItem this[int i] { get; set; }
    IEnsemble<TItem> this[Range range] { get; }
    int Length { get; }
}

public interface IEnsemble<TItem, out TEnsemble> : IEnsemble<TItem> where TEnsemble : IEnsemble<TItem, TEnsemble>
{
    new TEnsemble this[Range range] { get; }
}

public class Sorter<TItem, TEnsemble> 
    where TEnsemble : IEnsemble<TItem, TEnsemble>, new()
    where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{
    public static TEnsemble MergeSort(Func<int, TEnsemble> creator, TEnsemble array)
    {
        if (array.Length > 1)
        {
            var left = MergeSort(creator, array[0..(array.Length / 2)]);
            var right = MergeSort(creator, array[(array.Length / 2)..]);
            return MergeSort(creator, left, right);
        }
        else { return array; }
    }

    public static TEnsemble MergeSort(Func<int, TEnsemble> creator, TEnsemble left, TEnsemble right)
    {
        int leftPointer = 0;
        int rightPointer = 0;
        var res = creator(left.Length + right.Length);
        while (leftPointer < left.Length || rightPointer < right.Length)
        {
            if (rightPointer == right.Length || (leftPointer < left.Length && left[leftPointer].CompareTo(right[rightPointer]) < 0))
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = left[leftPointer];
                leftPointer++;
            }
            else
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = right[rightPointer];
                rightPointer++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

With the concrete implementation modified as follows:

```
public static partial class EnsembleExtensions
{
    public static Ensemble<TItem> OrderByMergeSort<TItem>(this Ensemble<TItem> ensemble) where TItem : IComparable<TItem> 
        => Sorter<TItem, Ensemble<TItem>>.MergeSort(l => new Ensemble<TItem>(l), ensemble);
}

public class Ensemble<TItem> : IEnsemble<TItem, Ensemble<TItem>>
{
    readonly TItem [] array;
    public Ensemble(int length) => this.array = new TItem[length];
    public Ensemble() : this(0) {}
    public Ensemble(TItem [] array) => this.array = array ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
    
    public int Length => array.Length;
    public TItem this[int i] { get => array[i]; set => array[i] = value; }
    public Ensemble<TItem> this[Range range] => new Ensemble<TItem>(array[range]);
    IEnsemble<TItem> IEnsemble<TItem>.this[Range range] => this[range];
}
```

.NET 5 demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HlpleY).

**As an alternative**, it is not entirely clear to me that abstracting an interface `IEnsemble<TItem>` adds any value to your design.  Do any of these apply?

- Are you planning to have a concrete type that implement multiple ensemble interfaces at once (multiple inheritance)?
- Are you planning to create multiple concrete types that implement the same ensemble interface, in the way that `List<T>`, `Collection<T>` and `T []` all implement `IList<T>`?
- Is `IEnsemble<TItem>` a contract that could be implemented by many different types?
- Do you need to mock its implementation for unit testing?

If none of the above apply, your could can be simplified by using only a concrete generic type, which could even be a `readonly struct` resembling [`ReadOnlyMemory<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.readonlymemory-1?view=net-7.0):

```
public static partial class EnsembleExtensions
{
    public static Ensemble<TItem> OrderByMergeSort<TItem>(this Ensemble<TItem> ensemble) where TItem : IComparable<TItem> 
        => Sorter<TItem>.MergeSort(ensemble);
}

public readonly struct Ensemble<TItem> 
{
    readonly TItem [] array;
    TItem [] Array => array ?? System.Array.Empty<TItem>();
    public Ensemble(int length) => this.array = new TItem[length];
    public Ensemble(TItem [] array) => this.array = array ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
    
    public int Length => array?.Length ?? 0;
    public TItem this[int i] { get => Array[i]; set => Array[i] = value; }
    public Ensemble<TItem> this[Range range] => new Ensemble<TItem>(Array[range]);
}

public class Sorter<TItem> where TItem : IComparable<TItem>
{
    public static Ensemble<TItem> MergeSort(Ensemble<TItem> array)
    {
        if (array.Length > 1)
        {
            var left = MergeSort(array[0..(array.Length / 2)]);
            var right = MergeSort(array[(array.Length / 2)..]);
            return MergeSort(left, right);
        }
        else { return array; }
    }

    public static Ensemble<TItem> MergeSort(Ensemble<TItem> left, Ensemble<TItem> right)
    {
        int leftPointer = 0;
        int rightPointer = 0;
        var res = new Ensemble<TItem>(left.Length + right.Length);
        while (leftPointer < left.Length || rightPointer < right.Length)
        {
            if (rightPointer == right.Length || (leftPointer < left.Length && left[leftPointer].CompareTo(right[rightPointer]) < 0))
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = left[leftPointer];
                leftPointer++;
            }
            else
            {
                res[leftPointer + rightPointer] = right[rightPointer];
                rightPointer++;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

See:

- *[When should one use interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1686174)*.
- *[Interfaces — What's the point?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6802573)*.
- *[Do I need to use an interface when only one class will ever implement it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/159813)*

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qtJQQc).

Comment: I'm using an interface since my other choice would be to define `MergeSort` twice, for each of the datatypes, and using an interface saves me from repeating some code. Of all the options you've listed (including simply using polymorphism instead of an interface), which one would you say is best practice in general?

Comment: @Anya - I'm not sure there is a "best practice" here, any solution that allows you to avoid duplicating code should be OK.  In C# 10 the static creation method should be fine.

Comment: @Anya - anyway, if the question is answered, please do [mark it as such](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147532). If not, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77335328/edit) your question to clarify where you need help.